# SSD M2 not recognized after graphics card change

Tags: ssd, graphics-card

I am having a very strange problem with my SSD M2. After I have changed my graphics card from MSI GTX 950 OC to Asus Strix RX580 8GB my SSD M2 is **not** **recognized** anymore by the PC. The HDD is fine all the time.

I found a strange fix which is:

- remove RX580 (new one)
- boot PC without monitor

Computer boots - m2 found.

Then I:

- add RX580

Computer BOOTS AGAIN! Everything works fine. But after 2-3 weeks, the m2 is not found again, even when the PC is on (idle). :(
The SSD is mounted BELOW the graphics card. I also mounted it above but no luck.

This is the only change I did to my PC. Rest of the components are the same.

PC Components:

- asrock h270 pro4
- Asus Strix RX580 8GB (the new "problematic" card) with NZXT Cooling (water) system.
- Samsung SSD 850 EVO M.2 250GB
- TOSHIBA HDWD110 - 1TB
- Intel Pentigum G4600
- 2x16GB G.Skrill DDR4 2400mhz
- be quite! 600w

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: At any point between when the configuration that works, and the configuration that does not work, has the firmware been updated?  What does the manual have to say with regards to what PCIe slots will be disabled when the M.2 slot you are using for your SSD is used?

Answer (score 0):

I guess so. It's possible for some sort of incompatibility issue to cause similar problems. Sometimes updating the BIOS/UEFI might fix it, sometimes updating the drive's firmware is a good idea and sometimes (like in your case) a simple OS update might do the trick.
Anyway, I'd suggest that you check the drive with a diagnostic tool (not just with the benchmark tool) to make sure that there are no errors whatsoever. And always keep a backup of your most important files, just to be on the safe side.

Cheers!

Comment: That's what I thought. The SSD has the latest firmware update and I've just updated the BIOS from 2.10 to 2.60 version. Let's see.

Comment: No luck. The updated BIOS didn't help out.
I've also noticed that when I unplugged the card (fan was still connected) the "trick" didn't work. It was successful when I removed the fan connector as well.